# Foundation SCSS Error: Incompatible units: 'em' and 'rem'

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I am having this issue when i try to compile my sass for foundation.

My foundation.scss file look like th following:

```
//  Settings
@import "global/settings"; // Foundation settings file.

// Foundation mixins & browser resets
@import '../../node_modules/foundation/scss/foundation';
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled foundation with the same result.

I also updated everything.

Full error:

```
[22:36:59] gulp-notify: [Sass Error] node_modules\foundation      \scss\foundation\components\_forms.scss
Error: Incompatible units: 'em' and 'rem'.
    on line 51 of node_modules/foundation/scss/foundation/components  /_forms.scss
>> $input-error-message-top:            -($form-spacing) - emCalc(5px) !default;
 -------------------------------------^
```

Literally any help on this would be fantastic.

Comment: This is literally what you would expect this to be. You are trying to subtract `em`s (from `emCalc(5px)`) from `rem`s (from `$form-spacing`). You cannot subtract apples from pears and expect it to return anything sensible, just like you can't subtract em's from rem's and expect anything sensible to be returned.

Comment: Well, this is coming from a foundation framework file? Is this a bug on their end?

Comment: I can't tell you. Figure out where `$form-spacing` is defined and if something is overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had a variable set to use rem and it should have been em in my settings.scss file and this was the culprit.